How to mock a static method that modifies an input and returns Unit with Mockk
I'm trying to use Mockk to mock the static method android.location.Location.distanceBetween().
Here's my test case:

class DistanceUtilsTest {

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        mockkStatic(Location::class)
        every { Location.distanceBetween(any(), any(), any(), any(), floatArrayOf()) } answers  {
            this.lastArg<FloatArray>()[0] = 655138f
        }
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        unmockkStatic(Location::class)
    }

    @Test
    fun `Should calculate large distance without error`() {
        // this function calls Location.distanceBetween
        val actual = DistanceUtils.calculateDistanceInMiles(lat1 = 90.0, lng1 = 100.0, lat2 = 0.0, lng2 = 0.0)
        val expected = 655138f
        Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}

I always get the error
Method distanceBetween in android.location.Location not mocked

The function takes in a float array as the last argument. I need the first argument in that float array to be some arbitrary number.

I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing. Does it work if you do mockkStatic(Location::distanceBetween) instead?

No, using mockkStatic(Location::distanceBetween) does nothing.

By the way, why are you calling MockKAnnotations.init without actually having any Mockk annotations? Just wondering if this is a cut-down version of something that would explain the behaviour.
